# Why scalar function of vector can only depend on norm of vector?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, vectors, invariants

In *Field Quantization* by Greiner and Reinhardt as well as *The Qunatum Theory of Fields* by Weinberg, concerning the spectral function, the authors say a scalar function of the four-vector $p^\mu$ can only depend on $p^2$ and the step function $\theta(p^0)$. More specifically, they argue that $\Sigma_n(2\pi)^3\delta^4(q-p_n)|\langle 0|\phi(0)|n\rangle|^2$ can be expressed as $\rho(q^2)\theta(q_0)$.

I cannot understand this statement. For example, $\delta^4(p-p_0)$ (where $p_0$ is some constant 4-vector) is a scalar function on $p$, but in no way can this function only depend on $p^2$ or $\theta(p)$. Can any one explain this to me?

Comment: Just to clarify: what's $p_0$ in this question? Some other, constant four-vector with units of momentum?

Comment: @DavidZ Yes，and I edited the question to specify the arguement

Comment: The Dirac delta is not a function.

Comment: But the original argument includes Delta function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is that your function does not transform under Lorentz transformations that take
$$ p^\mu \to {\Lambda^\mu}_\nu p^\nu.$$
To build invariants from one vector there is only the possibility to construct the invariant product with itself
$$ p^2 \equiv p^\mu p_\mu \to p^\mu p_\mu.$$
There is one more thing though. [The Lorentz group has two branches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Connected_components): Momenta with positive time-like component (i.e. positive energies) will never get boosted to momenta with negative energy, and thus
$\theta(p_0)$ also is invariant under Lorentz transformations.

Summary: Only $p^2$ is invariant under the full Lorentz group; in addition $\theta(p_0)$ (where $p_0$ is the zero-component and NOT a different four-vector!!) is invariant if one restricts to the Lorentz transformations from one branch (i.e. excludes time reversal operations).

Edit: True, $\delta^4(p^\mu - q^\mu)$ is also an invariant function. This can be seen by looking at how it operates on a Lorentz-invariant test function $f(p^2)$:
$$ \int \mathrm d^4p \delta^4(p^\mu - q^\mu) f(p^2) = f(q^2)$$
The cheapskate explanation is that since $\mathrm d^4p$ and $f(p^2)$ are invariant, as is $f(q^2)$, so must be $\delta^4(p^\mu - q^\mu)$. But this can be seen more explicitly as well. Let us perform a Lorentz transformation on the left hand side of the above equation:
$$\int\mathrm d^4p \delta^4(p^\mu - q^\mu) f(p^2) \to \int \mathrm d^4 p' \delta^4({\Lambda^\mu}_\nu (p^\nu - q^\nu)) f(p^2)$$
Here I already used that the measure picks up a factor of the determinant of the transformation but $\vert \Lambda \vert = 1$ for Lorentz transformations. We can then use that $\delta(\alpha x) = \delta(x) \frac{1}{\vert \alpha \vert}$, which also works for matrices (check that, it's a good excercise!) - where for matrices the $\vert \cdot \vert$ is the determinant. So $\delta^4({\Lambda^\mu}_\nu (p^\nu - q^\nu)) = \frac{1}{\vert \Lambda \vert} \delta^4(p^\nu - q^\nu) = \delta^4(p^\mu - q^\mu)$.

Comment: Can u explain that how $\delta^4(p-p_0)$ can be expressed by $p^2$? Or it is not an invariant function? I don't think $p^2$ can determine the value of $\delta^4(p-p_0)$. Here $p_0$ is a constant vector.

Comment: Can't you have a third step function that is equivalent to a choice of parity, since you can independently choose a parity and a time-orientation,a nd the Lorentz transforms will respect that?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Yes, in principle you could constrain parity as well with a step function and still get a full continuous branch of Lorentz transformations. But this is usually not done, since it is simply not needed, and if you don't fix parity your result is valid in a more general way.

Comment: @ChongWang I added a paragraph to my answer detailing how $\delta^4$ reacts.

Comment: The point is that if $\delta^4$ is invariant, how can $\delta^4(p-p_0)$ only depend on $p^2$. The function just seems to depend on every component of $p$

Comment: It is true that $\delta^4(p-q)$ can not be written as a function of $p^2$. But if I interpret your initial post correctly, the result they claim depends on $q$ and not on $p$, i.e. they have implicitly performed the $p$-integration.

Comment: Yeah, but how to evaluate $\rho$? That is , given a number $x$, how to evaluate $\rho(x)$? I suppose i should generate a $q$ which fulfills $q^2=x$ and then insert $q$ into that cumbersome expression. But i am not sure the result is independent of the choice of $q$

Comment: @ChongWang $\rho(q^2)$ is just a template, saying that you can express the result as a (possibly complicated) function, which depends on $q$ only through the Lorentz-invariant combination $q^2$. Thus you can calculate it in one specific reference frame and the result will be the same in any inertial frame.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I don't think every invariant function $\rho(q)$ depends on $q$ only through the $q^2$. For example, $\rho(q)=\delta^4(q-q_0)$.($q_0$ a constant 4-vector)

Answer (score 0):

A function of $p_{\mu}$, $T^{\mu\nu...}p_{\mu}p_{\nu}...$is invariant under Lorentz transformation if and only if  $T^{\mu\nu...}$ is a invariant tensor. However, there is only one invariant tensor for Lorentz group. That is $\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}$. Thus, each saclar function of $p_{\mu}$ must be a function of $p^2=\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}p_{\mu}p^{\nu}$. ($\epsilon^{\mu\nu\delta\gamma}$ is invariant under proper orthochronous Lorentz transformation, but not the whole Lorentz transformation). For more detail, see, for instance, W. K. Tung, *Group Theory in Physics*.